# xvfb-run works in shell but not when running from php exec() command

Tags: php, nightmare

I'm trying to get nightmarejs to work on my centos server and was able to do so by running xvfb-run however I need to call this command via a php exec() function.

when I do I'm just getting an empty result as though it doesn't work?

When I run it via command line (i.e. xvfb-run node my-script.js) everything works great. Any idea why it doesn't seem to work or be available to my php script?

Comment: Executing stuff via `php` `exec` it's a baaaad idea...

Answer (score 2):

Although Cono's answer does work, it is less secure as it gives YOUR_USER access to wheel, making YOUR_USER an administrator.

Instead, create a file in /etc/sudoers.d (RHEL/CentOS) with contents like: (presuming YOUR_USER is apache)

```
# Allow apache to run xvfb-run

Defaults:apache !requiretty
Defaults:apache visiblepw

apache ALL = NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/xvfb-run
```

This way, if the apache user is compromised they can only run the xvfb-run command.

(Answer thanks to ThirdNode)

Answer (score 1):

Ok i figured it out. Basically, sudo access has to be granted for xvfb-run in order to call it via an executable script in php. To do so, log into terminal and do the following:

```
# sudo visudo
```

Make sure the wheel group is uncommented

```
%wheel  ALL=(ALL)       ALL
```

This means that users added to the wheel group will have access to call sudo commands

At the bottom of the file, grant your user access to the script

```
YOUR_USER ALL = NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/xvfb-run
```

Save your file and add your user to the wheel group

```
usermod -aG wheel YOUR_USER
```

finally, from your php script you can now call xvfb-run via sudo

```
<?php exec('sudo xvfb-run node my-script.js'); ?>
```